# create boxplot with year bars from continuous date data with fill

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot with two different fills with continuous date data over years (but just one bar per year). my data looks quite simple:

```
date,       number,  type
2007-06-07  2        tot
2007-06-09  3        tot
2007-06-12  0        gps
```

So I imported my data and formated the date with te `as.Date` function and it worked. I changed all my NA to 0. Then I tried the following code:

```
p1 <- ggplot(sights, aes(x =date, y = number, group=date, fill = type)) + 
 geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7)

 p1
```

I got a plot like:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW7PQ.jpg)

So i tried codes like:

```
  p1 <- p1+scale_x_date(breaks = as.Date(c("2005", "2006", "2007","2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013",  "2014","2015", "2016","2017","2018")))                                          
p1
```

but it doesnt work. It would be amazing to get some help! I would also like to do the same after month ;)

EDIT: I had some outliers at around year 2101. I deleted them and now i get:
[plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3r4t.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a case in your full data with an incorrect date (> 2100)?

Comment: oh jesus i do have! its always the little things that kill.. let me check how it changes..

Comment: I removed the outliers but i still dont get the graph im looking for. i edited the post with the new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this output close to what you want?

```
sights %>% 
  mutate(year = format.Date(date, "%Y")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = number, fill = type)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7)
```

Comment: oh thats a good one! I thought about manually adding another column with just the year, but with format.date it works well! Just without the group =year comment tho :) Thanks!